# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream Nodejs Elastick Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a log nodejs backend code here and it runs on port 8080.

process.env.PORT = 8080 in the environment varisbles.

```
var port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log("Port is", port);
})
```

It connects to the databse as I see the output in the log file :

```
Port is 8080
```

I get an error in the log file with the following.

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 777.77.7.777, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://111.1.1.1:8080/", host: "666.66.66.666"
```

Does anyone know why it errors?
Should the host:  be my elastic beanstalk url by any chance?

If you need any additinal info let me know!

Comment: `5432` is for postgresql, so what are you doing? Connection to postgesql database?

Comment: I  corrected it to 8080 and it gives the same error